# Live search engine not working

Tags: php, html, search

I want to create a live search engine on my site. I've copied this from:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

This is my HTML by the script. What am I doing wrong?

My site is not online on a server yet, could that be the problem?

I saved the files in the exact same types as in the description on w3schools.

HTML:

```
<div class="top_search fl">
    <form name="searchForm" method="get" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)"
        <div class="search_default">                
            <input type="text" class="search_box" placeholder="Search for network " name="keywords" id="livesearch"/>
```

Above this code I pasted the HTML code from w3 schools.

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?  This is a good opportunity to take a look at your browser's debugging tools.  Is there an error on the developer console?  Is the JavaScript code invoked at all?  What does `showResult()` do?

Comment: do you have a local server installed? (such as wamp, easyphp, ..)

Comment: `onkeyup="showResult(this.value)"` won't work in the form element (it's originally in 'input'). Also you missed a closing `>` there.